# Selenium implicit dependency

Tags: maven, selenium

I am developing a selenium based automation framework in java .While unit testing it is found that one error is thrown while initializing a webdriver.
 "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/net/MediaType".
When I google it ,some sites suggest me to include com.google.guava dependency.
Is it necessary? Any way I added it in my pom and now it is working,But my doubt is, in previous version of my project does not contain such dependency& it working fine. In this project I just upgraded my selenium jar version.Please share you people's thought.

Comment: Selenium has always had a dependency on Guava, so even with an older version, you probably had it. With the new version, you definitely should have it. The `MediaType` class has also been in Guava for ages, so that should not be an issue. From which version to which version did you upgrade?

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>2.45.0</version>
  </dependency>This is  the only dependency I had for my old version